# How to assign a function to the default add button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nuget-package

I'm using dragablz nuget package where they have a default add button to add  new tabs, in order to get it you have to set  ShowDefaultAddButton to true in the XAML file.

[image]

I want to assign a function to that button circled in red

[image]

Comment: Please, remove that picture and add the real xaml code... it is terrible.

Comment: Additionalluy we would have to see the actual control that hold the button, normally you would bind `ICommand` to button command `<Button Command = "{Binding SomeCommand}"/>` and start that void/task from this ICommand implementation.

Comment: https://wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/